# Sitecore PowerShell Remoting doesn't work with http://localhost/ and http://127.0.0.1/ addresses

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions, powershell, docker

I have Sitecore 9.3 with SXA and SPE 6.0 installed in a Docker container.

`docker-compose.yml` map containers 80 port to 80 on local machine.

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

I have an additional configuration in hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   test.dev.local
```

Website is available in a browser on my machine by any of these 3 addresses:

1. http://test.dev.local/
2. http://localhost/
3. http://127.0.0.1/

And I can confirm that it is the same website.

But Sitecore Powershell Remoting works only with http://test.dev.local/
[image]

You can see that Powershell script was able to return get `admin` user only when I used `http://test.dev.local/` as `ConnectionUri`

What does need to be changed to allow Sitecore Powershell Remoting to work with `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` URL addresses?

P.S. I want to use either `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` because inside the container Windows and IIS doesn't know anything about `test.dev.local` host. And host is important for SXA Export context(SXA export fails if address is not resolved). I am able to overcome this issue by settings

```
networks: 
  dev.local: 
    aliases: 
      - test.dev.local
```

in the `docker-compose.yml` file. But is not a very convenient solution for my case.

Comment: Try to run the command with `-Verbose` flag to see more information about the process. Also if you have a local IIS make sure it's stopped.

Comment: @siaznik Yes, local IIS is stopped. I can confirm it: when I login to http://localhost/, http://127.0.0.1/ or http://test.dev.local/ I see the same Sitecore that is inside Docker container.

I have updated question with image of executing using -Verbose flag, but it didn't provide any useful information.